# How to solve may not be abstract and must be include a default constructor?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, charts, canvasjs

I have a database [![as this picture][1]][1]

I want to get a chart from this database and when I tried to use SQL query on the controller side, I got an error like this ;
[![this is error type][2]][2]
This is my controller code ;

```
 public ActionResult Index2(String makineadi, DateTime? startdate, DateTime? enddate)
        {
            var data = entities.Database.SqlQuery<DataPoint>("SELECT Sıcaklık, Recete_Sure From Recete Where Machine_IP ='" + makineadi + "' and Tarih between'"+startdate+"' and '"+enddate+"'").ToList();
            ViewBag.DataPoints = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            return View();
        }
```

And here is my class definition for getting the chart to JSON serialization;

```
 [DataContract]
        public class DataPoint
        {
            public DataPoint(int Sıcaklık, int Recete_Sure)
            {
                this.Sıcaklık = Sıcaklık;
                this.Recete_Sure = Recete_Sure;
            }

            //Explicitly setting the name to be used while serializing to JSON.
            [DataMember(Name = "Sıcaklık")]
            public Nullable<int> Sıcaklık { get; set; }

        //Explicitly setting the name to be used while serializing to JSON.
        [DataMember(Name = "Recete_Sure")]
            public Nullable<int> Recete_Sure { get; set; }
        }
```

What should I do to fix it?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObwWR.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQNgO.png

Answer (score 0):

Add default constructor in class.

```
[DataContract]
public class DataPoint
{
    public DataPoint()
    {
    }
    public DataPoint(int Sıcaklık, int Recete_Sure)
    {
        this.Sıcaklık = Sıcaklık;
        this.Recete_Sure = Recete_Sure;
    }

    //Explicitly setting the name to be used while serializing to JSON.
    [DataMember(Name = "Sıcaklık")]
    public Nullable<int> Sıcaklık { get; set; }

    //Explicitly setting the name to be used while serializing to JSON.
    [DataMember(Name = "Recete_Sure")]
    public Nullable<int> Recete_Sure { get; set; }
}
```

It will resolve issue